# OpenGL Polygon rendering mode and texture mapping

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

asked a question on my project earlier but it seems im learning more about how little i know of openGL than how much i do at the moment, but ever answer i get is feeding my knowledge so thanks in advance!

Ok so currently my car shape is drawn using GL_LINE_LOOP and looks like this.
[image: car shape]

The image i want to map onto the body of the car looks like this.
[image: car picture]

I know my shape the picture isnt perfect but im attempting to put that picture within my lines so that it gives at least some impression of the car im modelling. i have attempted this using the following code:

```
void drawBody(int textureindex)
{
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLib[textureindex]);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glTexCoord2f(0.0F, 0.0F);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(-0.97, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-1.97f, 0.0f);
//wheel arch begin.
glTexCoord2f(-0.93, 0.3);
glVertex2f(-1.93f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(-0.95, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-1.95f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.2, 0.6);
glVertex2f(-2.2f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.6, 0.6);
glVertex2f(-2.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.82, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-2.82f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.8, 0.3);
glVertex2f(-2.8f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.78, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-2.78f, 0.0f);
//end wheel arch.
//Front of car.
glTexCoord2f(-2.8, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-3.8f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(-2.7, 0.2);
glVertex2f(-3.7f, 0.2f);
glTexCoord2f(-2.8, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-3.8f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.8, 0.7);
glVertex2f(-2.8f, 0.7f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.4, 0.7);
glVertex2f(-2.4f, 0.7f);
//Windscreen.
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.5, 1.05);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 1.05f);
glTexCoord2f(3.3, 0.8);
glVertex2f(2.3f, 0.8f);
//rear bumper.
glTexCoord2f(3.15, 0.5);
glVertex2f(2.15f, 0.5f);
glTexCoord2f(3.15, 0.3);
glVertex2f(2.15f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(3.35, 0.3);
glVertex2f(2.35f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(3.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(2.83, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.83f, 0.0f);
//wheel arch begin.
glTexCoord2f(2.85, 0.3);
glVertex2f(1.85f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(2.86, 0.4);
glVertex2f(1.86f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(2.6, 0.6);
glVertex2f(1.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(2.2, 0.6);
glVertex2f(1.2f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.4);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.3);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(2.05, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.05f, 0.0f);
//end wheel arch.
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Which results in this awfullness

[image: awful car]

Two problems. one is cleary my coords for texturing are really wrong and secondly i dont know how to stop the polygon mode from getting rid of the wheel arches :/ help on these two fronts would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texture coordinates should be in the range [0, 1].

The wheel arches problem is because OpenGL only renders convex polygons. Use the [tessellation facilities](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html) to convert concave polygons into triangle meshes.

P.S.: For OpenGL's immediate mode, I suggest you adopt a different coding style that is vastly easier to read and maintain:

```
void drawBody(int textureindex)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLib[textureindex]);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glTexCoord2f( 0.0 , 0.0 ); glVertex2f(-1.0 , 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f(-0.97, 0.0 ); glVertex2f(-1.97, 0.0 );

    // Wheel arch
    glTexCoord2f(-0.93, 0.3 ); glVertex2f(-1.93, 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f(-0.95, 0.4 ); glVertex2f(-1.95, 0.4 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.2 , 0.6 ); glVertex2f(-2.2 , 0.6 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.6 , 0.6 ); glVertex2f(-2.6 , 0.6 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.82, 0.4 ); glVertex2f(-2.82, 0.4 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.8 , 0.3 ); glVertex2f(-2.8 , 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.78, 0.0 ); glVertex2f(-2.78, 0.0 );

    // Front of car
    glTexCoord2f(-2.8 , 0.0 ); glVertex2f(-3.8 , 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f(-2.7 , 0.2 ); glVertex2f(-3.7 , 0.2 );
    glTexCoord2f(-2.8 , 0.4 ); glVertex2f(-3.8 , 0.4 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.8 , 0.7 ); glVertex2f(-2.8 , 0.7 );
    glTexCoord2f(-1.4 , 0.7 ); glVertex2f(-2.4 , 0.7 );

    // Windscreen
    glTexCoord2f( 0.0 , 1.0 ); glVertex2f(-1.0 , 1.0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 1.5 , 1.05); glVertex2f( 0.5 , 1.05);
    glTexCoord2f( 3.3 , 0.8 ); glVertex2f( 2.3 , 0.8 );

    // Rear bumper
    glTexCoord2f( 3.15, 0.5 ); glVertex2f( 2.15, 0.5 );
    glTexCoord2f( 3.15, 0.3 ); glVertex2f( 2.15, 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f( 3.35, 0.3 ); glVertex2f( 2.35, 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f( 3.0 , 0.0 ); glVertex2f( 2.0 , 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.83, 0.0 ); glVertex2f( 1.83, 0.0 );

    // Wheel arch
    glTexCoord2f( 2.85, 0.3 ); glVertex2f( 1.85, 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.86, 0.4 ); glVertex2f( 1.86, 0.4 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.6 , 0.6 ); glVertex2f( 1.6 , 0.6 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.2 , 0.6 ); glVertex2f( 1.2 , 0.6 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.0 , 0.4 ); glVertex2f( 1.0 , 0.4 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.0 , 0.3 ); glVertex2f( 1.0 , 0.3 );
    glTexCoord2f( 2.05, 0.0 ); glVertex2f( 1.05, 0.0 );

    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: well i dont understand the last bit for now so ill do a bit of reading up but as for the first bit i have changed all my coords to be in the range of 0 to 1 and its still a bit funny, im assuming im matching the wrong texture coords with the shape :(

Comment: I did a typo; I meant, "…convert concave polygons…". Without seeing the funny shape I can only guess: perhaps it's because the texture car's outline doesn't perfectly align with the polygon.

Comment: it squishes the image into the back half of the shape and then adds a little bit of the image into a white space at the front :/
http://i378.photobucket.com/albums/oo230/tcc_hellgate/carnew.png

Comment: @MikeTarrant: Are you sure that all your texture coordinates have been fixed up? It looks like part of your original mapping is still there. Also, it looks like you might have mapped your texture x-coordinates to [-1, 1], not [0, 1]. Another possibility is that OpenGL is misbehaving because you've given it a concave polygon to render.

Comment: @MikeTarrant: I suggest you add to your question the revised version of your code and the resulting image. When you do, please follow the coding-style advice I just appended to my answer.

Comment: thanks for that style of coding. it does look much neater so thanks :) and yeh i think the fact that its concave might be the problem.. trying to tesselate now if i can figure that out :)